# Quitar marca de agua PDFTRON en Angular 8

Tags: angular

estoy utilizando angular 8 y pdftron como visor de archivos pero no puedo quitar la marca de agua que se visualiza cuando muestro un documento:
[image: Esa marca de agua]

puedo deshabiltar algunas opciones como dice la documentación pero no puedo borrar esa marca de agua, me podrían ayudar con este inconveniente, el metodo lo tengo de la siguiente manera:

```
WebViewer({
  path: '../lib',
  initialDoc: '../files/repositorio.pdf'
}, this.viewer.nativeElement).then(instance => {

  this.wvInstance = instance;

  instance.disableElement('downloadButton');
  instance.disableElement('freeHandToolGroupButton');
  .
  .
  .
)}
```

Comment: Es código licenciado al parecer. Puede que esa sea la razón.

Comment: Pudiste solucionar eso?? o al menos cambiar la marca de agua?? a mi en el mac me funciona perfecto pero en el server no me funciona solo me dice que esta en modo demo Saludos